# Injecting service object into guice module

Tags: playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

I'm using  PlayFramework (java) and Guice for DI, along with pac4j. This is what my Guice module looks like based on [pac4j demo app](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo/blob/master/app/modules/SecurityModule.java). In the code, I pass a CustomAuthentication in which I inject a SericeDAO object, however it is always **null**.

Initial thought was because I was creating CustomAuthenticator rather than letting guice create it, thus why it was null. I also tried injecting CustomAuthenticator directly into the security module - customAuthenticator object was then null. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class SecurityModule extends AbstractModule {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final Configuration configuration;

    public SecurityModule(
            Environment environment,
            Configuration configuration) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        final String baseUrl = configuration.getString("baseUrl");

        // HTTP
        final FormClient formClient = new FormClient(baseUrl + "/loginForm", new CustomAuthenticator());

        final Clients clients = new Clients(baseUrl + "/callback", formClient);

        final Config config = new Config(clients);
        bind(Config.class).toInstance(config);

    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticator impl:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator implements UsernamePasswordAuthenticator {

    @Inject
    private ServiceDAO dao;

    @Override
    public void validate(UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials) {
        Logger.info("got to custom validation");
        if(dao == null) {
            Logger.info("dao is null, fml"); // Why is this always null? :(
        }
    }
}
```

The ServiceDAO is already setup as a guice module

```
public class ServiceDAOModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ServiceDAO.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

First, anything you construct using *new* will not have injection with @Inject working. 
Second, you cannot inject stuff into a module.

To solve this problem, refactor your code like this.

1. make sure that the ServiceDaoModule is loaded before the other module.
2. refactor the security module as follows:

   1. remove all constructor arguments / the constructor as a whole
   2. bind the CustomAuthenticator as eager singleton
   3. create and bind a Provider. There you can @Inject the Configuration.
   4. create and bind a Provider, this one can @Inject Configuration and a FormClient
   5. create and bind a Provider, which @Inject Clients.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.